# Node.js child-process only exits after stdout.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, casperjs, child-process

I've built a simple web interface using Node.js with socket.io that I'm using to run browser automation tests by kicking off a CapserJS child process.

The CasperJS child-process fails to exit properly unless I attach a `stdout.on('data')` handler. If I don't have this handler in my code, my `exit` handler never gets called and the CasperJS process is left orphaned. What am I doing wrong? Does my child-process require me to pipe it's output before the process can end?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('run tests', function(data) {
      if (runningProcess) {
         io.emit('alert', 'Please wait for current test run to finish');
         return;
      }

      var command = spawn(
         'casperjs',
         [
            'test',
            'yadda.js',
            '--user="' + data.user + '"',
            '--password="' + data.password + '"',
            '--server="' + data.server + '"',
            '--port="' + data.port + '"'
         ]
      );

      runningProcess = true;

      // Only exits when un-commented
      // command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      //    io.emit('line out', data.toString());
      // });

      command.on('exit', function(data) {
         runningProcess = false;
         io.emit('finished');
      });
   });
});
```